# Why does VSTS require GIT credential managers instead of just a simple username/password?

Tags: git, macos, azure-devops

I just set up Git to work with VSTS on visualstudio.com but I'm confused about the roundabout credential managers I had to use to get it to work especially on MacOS.

What's the reason for these requirements as opposed to simply entering my username and password for git hosted on VSTS?

Answer (score 2):

The credential manager allows for two factor authentication.

You can just use various other mechanisms for authentication one of which is alternate credentials which is essentially username, password.

See more details here- [Authenticate with your Git Repos - VSTS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/auth-overview)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use the credential manager -- you can also authenticate with SSH:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate

Answer (score 0):

Using git credential manager (GCM), you only need to authenticate for the first time. It will save you to authenticate every time.

> Once authenticated, the credential manager will create and cache a
>   personal access token for future connections to the repo. Git commands
>   that connect to this account will not prompt for user credentials
>   until the token expires or is revoked through Team Services/TFS

You can view detail about GCM fot mac [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/11/18/git-credential-manager-for-mac-and-linux/).

And git credential managers is not essential if you want to enter username and password every time. You can refer this instructions to [install/uninstall GCM](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Mac-and-Linux/blob/master/Install.md).